# Converting XML to CSV Xpath not picking up anything

Tags: php, xml, xpath

What am I doing wrong for xpath to not be picking up anything? This function works fine on another xml file with a bit less depth to it.

```
function xml2csv($xmlFile, $xPath) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
    $path = $xml->xpath($xPath);
    $csvData = '';
    foreach($path as $item) {
        foreach($item as $key => $value) {
            $csvData .= '"' . trim($value) . '"' . ',';
        }
        $csvData = trim($csvData, ',');
        $csvData .= "\n";

    }
    return $csvData;
}
```

**XML being used**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bl>
    <section>
        <grade gradeLevel="1">
            <level dirname="The folder of pdfs">
                <file filename="hello_world.pdf">Hello world</file>
                <file filename="the_avengers.pdf">The Avengers</file>
                <file filename="batman.pdf">Batman</file>
            </level>
        </grade>
    </section>
</bl>
```

When calling `xml2csv('test.xml', 'bl');` nothing is returned, same with anything after it `bl/section/grade/*` etc etc, also tried singular targetting.
I'm expecting to at least have the file names outputted..

**XML that seem to work just fine** I can target the xml below using the same method above `xml2csv('cars.xml', 'car');`

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<cars>
    <car>
        <color>blue</color>
        <price>2000</price>
    </car>
    <car>
        <color>red</color>
        <price>10000</price>
    </car> 
    <car>
        <color>black</color>
        <price>5000</price>
    </car>
</cars>
```

**Cars XML outputs**

```
"blue","2000"
"red","10000"
"black","5000"
```

Comment: have you tried "//file" for your xpath?  that should select all file nodes anywhere in the source document.

Comment: Haven't you simplified the XML by removing a namespace declaration somewhere (`xmlns`)?

Answer (score 0):

Had to modify the original xml2csv function in order to relate. Targeted using `section/grade`.

**Update function** still working in progress

```
function xml2csv($xmlFile, $xPath) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
    $path = $xml->xpath($xPath);
    $csvData = '';
    foreach($path as $item) {
        $attributes = $item->attributes();
        $gradeLevel = $attributes['gradeLevel'];
        foreach ($item->level as $level) {
            foreach ($level->file as $file) {
                $csvData .= '"' . trim($gradeLevel) . '"' . ',';
                $csvData .= '"' . trim($level->attributes()->dirname) . '"' . ',';
                $csvData .= '"' . trim($file->attributes()->filename) . '"' . ',';
                $csvData .= '"' . trim($file) . '"' . ',';
                $csvData .= "\n";

            }

        }
        $csvData = trim($csvData, ',');
        $csvData .= "\n";
    }
    return $csvData;
}
```